# C# checking a whole char for numbers

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, foreach, char

Hello i got a string that im converting to a char 
and cheking if it has a digit but i got a bug when i type like 
122Abssde it goes thru anny suggestions?

```
foreach (char cha in myString)
{
    if(char.IsDigit(cha))
    {
       return Int32.Parse(MyString)
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i got a bug_ exactly? Can you please be more specific? BTW, I hope you mean `IsDigit` instead of `ISDigit`.

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking here.

Comment: Use `int.TryParse` instead of whole your code.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like taking risk to answer that but you can use [`Enumerable.All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with `char.IsDigit` method and parse it to int like;

```
if(myString.All(char.IsDigit))
{
   return int.Parse(myString);
}
```

Or better, use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to check your string is valid integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

write a function

```
public static bool isNumeric(string val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
{
    Int32 result;
    return Int32.TryParse(val, NumberStyle,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);
}
```

usage

```
var _isNumeric2 = isNumeric("9.", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);
```